# How to use DataGrid.Columns with comboBox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpfdatagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

its complicated becasue im doing copy list by the object UserX.. 
I have users list and i want to display them in table.
I need that in the Role column the default value of the comboBox will be the user's current role, and I need option to change this role by using ComboBox and I dont know how ( the possible roles are: Administrator, Manager and Employee)

thank you for your help. Here is the code:

XAML

```
  <DataGrid FontSize="20" Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding list}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username}" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Password}" />
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Role" ItemsSource="{Binding Role}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Remove">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Click="ButtonRemove" Content="Remove User"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

CS

```
        List<User> users = user.getUsersList();
        List<Userx> updated = new List<Userx>();
        //coping from  the list users to list updated. I did it to gete the binding 
        for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
            updated.Add(new Userx() { Id = i + 1, Username = users.ElementAt(i).getUsername(),
                                                    Password = users.ElementAt(i).GetPassword(),
                                                    Role = users.ElementAt(i).getRole() });            
        dgUsers.ItemsSource = updated;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with below code? To **ComboBoxSelectedItem** property add the current role.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid FontSize="20" Name="dgUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding list}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="#" Binding="{Binding Id}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" Binding="{Binding Username}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Password" Binding="{Binding Password}" />
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn  Header="Role" ItemsSource="{Binding Role}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ComboBoxSelectedItem}" />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Remove">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Click="ButtonRemove" Content="Remove User"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```